# Trouble with Multiple Substitute / Replace Function in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have 1000+ lines of data that are in the format: "Enclosure - Holes - Large 2"" or greater",Rust - Heavy,"Pad - Large hole 2"" or greater". I am trying to set a Substitute or Replace function that will replace the commas with a backslash and remove all unnecessary apostrophes in a faster way.

I am having issues making a formula that will replace multiple values at once. In my case I need to replace ',' with '/'. I also need to replace all excess apostrophes. Example Below:

Data in Excel:

```
"Enclosure - Holes - Large 2"" or greater",Rust - Heavy,"Pad - Large hole 2"" or greater"
```

With Formatting:

```
Enclosure - Holes - Large 2" or greater / Rust - Heavy / Pad - Large hole 2" or greater
```

I've tried using the Substitute function and Replace function, however, excel isn't liking that I am searching for apostrophes in the function itself.

Find/Replace works, but it is not time effective.

```
Substitute(AU2,","," / ")
Substitute(AU2,""E", "E")
Substitute(AU2, """", """)
Substitute(AU2,"r"", "r")
```

When I put all of the code above into one formula, I expected the formatting to appear like it is above in #1. However, Excel is giving an error that the formula is not valid.

Comment: Is there any reason this has to be code and can't be solved using the Find & Select and replace from there?

Comment: Can you show us an example of the code you've used already? I see you have the formula sort of in there, but it would be more helpful to have it in the right format so we can check it better.

Comment: You don't show the formula you are actually using.

Answer (score 1):

You never define "unnecessary" but it seems, from your examples, that you want to

- replace all double quotes with single quotes
- remove all the single quotes
- replace the commas with slashes.

You can use the following formula which

- replaces all double quotes with an unused character
- removes all the remaining single quotes
- replace the commas with slashes

*Note that in order to quote the quote mark, one way is to "double up".  Another would be to use `CHAR(34)`*

It works on your example:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"""""",CHAR(1)),"""",""),CHAR(1),""""),",","/")
```

If that is not what you want, then clarify your question.

Comment: Thank you Ron! This is exactly what I wanted